# How to use individual dates for a month as a condition

Tags: java, sql

I am working on a script where I need to keep checking for individual dates for a month. So far, I can directly check for a month, but I need it for a day, as it returns multiple values for a day.

The code is as follows:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE end_datetime BETWEEN '2015-03-01 00:00:00' and '2015-04-01 00:00:00'
```

I need a code in java, where I can check for individual dates (example - between '2015-03-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-02 00:00:00'; between '2015-03-02 00:00:00' and '2015-03-03 00:00:00' and so on, till the last date is reached, which is '2015-04-01 00:00:00'.

Comment: What about using `YEAR()` and `MONTH` function instead?

Comment: `where date(end_datetime) = '2015-03-01'`? `between` is inclusive, so you're allowing  "midnight tomorrow" to be part of "today".

Answer (score 3):

## Half-Open

A common approach in date-time work is "Half-Open" (or Half-Closed). The idea is to making the beginning moment *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a week runs from a Monday to a Monday, an hour runs from 02:00 to 03:00, and a day runs from `2015-03-01 00:00:00` to `2015-03-02 00:00:00`. In other words, a day runs from the first moment of a day and goes up to, but does not include, the first moment of the next day.

This approach avoids various problem. The main problem is trying to determine the last moment of the day with infinite fractional second resolved to whole seconds or milliseconds or microseconds or nanoseconds. Better to say "The First of March is any date-time value >= 2015-03-01 00:00:00 AND < 2015-03-02 00:00:00" with an `=` in the first criterion but not in the second.

This means not using `BETWEEN` in SQL. Use a pair of comparisons `>=` and `<`.

Example SQL for obtaining events happening on first of March this year.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM event_
WHERE ( when_ >= '2015-03-01 00:00:00' ) 
AND ( when_ < '2015-03-02 00:00:00' )
;
```

## Time Zone

The example above has a serious problem. It assumes we mean "today" in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) time zone. Or perhaps the SQL session’s current default time zone is applied and adjusts the values. Either way it is messy.

Better to specify your desired/expected time zone rather than implicitly rely on some default.

If those date-time values were meant to be midnights in Montréal Québec, then we should say so. The word "midnight" seems to create confusion in this context of computer programming. I prefer the phrase "first moment of the day".

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM event_
WHERE ( when_ >= '2015-03-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Montreal'  ) 
AND ( when_ < '2015-03-02 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Montreal'  )
;
```

### Month

This same logic applies to doing a month. Go from first moment of March to first moment of April.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM event_
WHERE ( when_ >= '2015-03-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Montreal'  ) 
AND ( when_ < '2015-04-01 00:00:00' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Montreal'  )
;
```

## Java

When working in Java, we can use the new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) built into Java 8 and later.

### ISO 8601

First, for convenience, we convert your input strings to comply with standard formats defined by [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). The java.time framework uses ISO 8601 by default when parsing and generating string representations of date-time values. So no need for us to define explicit formatters.

```java
String inputStart = "2015-03-01 00:00:00";  // Month of March.
String inputStop = "2015-04-01 00:00:00";

String inputStartStandard = inputStart.replace( " " , "T" );
String inputStopStandard = inputStop.replace( " " , "T" );
```

### `LocalDateTime`

I assume your input strings represent the first moment of days in a certain time zone. I'll arbitrarily go with Québec as an example. The actual input strings lack any such information, so first we parse them as "homeless" LocalDateTime values without any time zone.

```java
java.time.LocalDateTime localStart = LocalDateTime.parse( inputStartStandard ); 
java.time.LocalDateTime localStop = LocalDateTime.parse( inputStopStandard );
```

Next we adjust them to Québec time zone.

```java
java.time.ZonedId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );  
java.time.ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ZonedDateTime.of( localStart , zoneId );
java.time.ZonedDateTime zdtStop = ZonedDateTime.of( localStop , zoneId );
```

### JDBC 4.2

Some day in the future we will be able to proceed to executing SQL at this point. But today most JDBC drivers have not yet been updated to [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170), so they cannot directly handle the new java.time types.

### Convert to old java.sql.Timestamp

While waiting for future JDBC drivers, we can use the new methods added to the old java.sql.Timestamp class to conveniently convert. The conversion requires an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object, which is a point on the timeline without time zone information (UTC basically). Our [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) offer a [`toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--) method, just what we need.

```java
java.sql.Timestamp tsStart = new java.sql.Timestamp( zdtStart.toInstant() );
java.sql.Timestamp tsStop = new java.sql.Timestamp( zdtStop.toInstant() );
```

### No data loss

Note that all these mentioned classes, ( java.sql.Timestamp, java.time. ZonedDateTime, and java.time.Instant ), have [nanosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) resolution of their fractional seconds. So no data loss involved going between them. Converting to the old java.util.Date/.Calendar or third-party [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library support only [millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) resolution, so may involve data loss.

Be aware of your database’s date-time resolution. Many databases such as [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) use [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond). Any value generated in java.time with nanoseconds will be truncated when saved to a database using microseconds. For example `2015-01-02 03:04:05.123456789` changes to `2015-01-02 03:04:05.123456`, only six digits of fractional second.

### `PreparedStatement`

Build the text for a SQL statement. While not required in this case, best to make a habit of [using `PreparedStatement`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to avoid [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security risk.

```java
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
sql.append( "SELECT * " ).append( "\n" );
sql.append( "FROM event_ " ).append( "\n" );
sql.append( "WHERE ( when_ >= ? ) " ).append( "\n" );
sql.append( "AND ( when_rc_ < ? ) " ).append( "\n" );
sql.append( "ORDER BY when_ ASC " ).append( "\n" );
sql.append( ";" )append( "\n" );
```

### Execute SQL

Lastly, execute the SQL. Pass the start and stop timestamp objects into the PreparedStatement.

```java
try ( Connection conn = DatabaseHelper.instance().connectionInAutoCommitMode() ; 
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement( sql.toString() ); ) {
    pstmt.setTimestamp( 1 , tsStart );
    pstmt.setTimestamp( 2 , tsStop );
    try ( ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); ) {
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            // …
        }
    }
} catch ( SQLException ex ) {
    logger.error( "SQLException during: " + message + "\n" + ex );
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
    logger.error( "Exception during: " + message + "\n" + ex );
}
```

All this example code was hand-written without running, untested.

### Day at a time

The Question is not clear. If you want a day at a time, loop by [adding a day](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#plusDays-long-) to the start.

```java
ZonedDateTime zdtNextDay = zdtStart.plusDays( 1 );
```

You can also get the beginning of next month similarly, with call to [`plusMonths( 1 )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#plusMonths-long-).

```java
ZonedDateTime zdtNextMonth = zdtStart.plusMonths( 1 );
```

You can test in your loop to see if the "next day" is still before the "next month" by calling [`isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-).

```java
if( zdtNextDay.isBefore( zdtNextMonth ) ) {
    …
}
```

### Complete month example

Here is a complete example of looping day-by-day of current month.

We must get the first moment of the day. To do that in java.time, we must start with a local date-only ([`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html)) where "local" means "any locality" without any specific time zone.  Then we assign both a time zone and a time-of-day by calling [`atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) to produce a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. You might think the day starts at the time `00:00:00` but no, not always. Some time zones such as [Palestine](http://www.worldtimeserver.com/current_time_in_PS.aspx) start Daylight Saving Time at midnight so the day starts at `01:00`.

The old date-time classes before java.time, such as java.sql.Timestamp, implement `toString` methods that implicitly apply the JVM’s [current default time zone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault--). Though done with good intentions, this approach proved to be confusing. We see this in the code below. This code shows that when run in the United States west coast time zone with offset of `-07:00`, midnight in Québec with offset of `-04:00` is three hours different. So midnight in Québec is reported as 9 PM (21:00) of the previous date out on the west coast.

```
java.time.ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdtThisMonthStart = LocalDate.now( zoneId ).withDayOfMonth( 1 ).atStartOfDay( zoneId );
java.time.ZonedDateTime zdtNextMonthStart = zdtThisMonthStart.plusMonths( 1 );
java.time.ZonedDateTime zdtDayStart = zdtThisMonthStart; // Initialize variable to be modified in loop.

System.out.println( "JVM’s current default time zone applied implicitly by java.sql.Timestamp’s 'toString' method: " + java.util.TimeZone.getDefault( ) );

while ( zdtDayStart.isBefore( zdtNextMonthStart ) ) {
    java.time.ZonedDateTime zdtNextDayStart = zdtDayStart.plusDays( 1 );
    java.sql.Timestamp tsStart = java.sql.Timestamp.from( zdtDayStart.toInstant( ) );
    java.sql.Timestamp tsStop = java.sql.Timestamp.from( zdtNextDayStart.toInstant( ) );

    System.out.print( "In java.time, Day is: [" + zdtDayStart + "/" + zdtNextDayStart + "]. " );
    System.out.println( "In java.sql.Timestamp, Day is: [" + tsStart + "/" + tsStop + "]" );

    //
    // … Do SQL work, such as the try-catch-catch seen above in this Answer.
    //

    // Prep for next loop. Increment to next day.
    zdtDayStart = zdtDayStart.plusDays( 1 );
}
```

When run.

```
JVM’s current default time zone applied implicitly by java.sql.Timestamp’s 'toString' method: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="US/Pacific",offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=185,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=US/Pacific,offset=-28800000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=3,startMonth=2,startDay=8,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=0,endMode=3,endMonth=10,endDay=1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=0]]
In java.time, Day is: [2015-08-01T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]/2015-08-02T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]]. In java.sql.Timestamp, Day is: [2015-07-31 21:00:00.0/2015-08-01 21:00:00.0]
…
In java.time, Day is: [2015-08-31T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]/2015-09-01T00:00-04:00[America/Montreal]]. In java.sql.Timestamp, Day is: [2015-08-30 21:00:00.0/2015-08-31 21:00:00.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

See if you need all data of dates then you first get all the records in single query order them by end_time. and then you can loop records.

Options 2:

You can also fetch records by date simply using '>' and '<' operator and you need to fire query in loop using prepared statement till last date is reached in loop. Keep increasing date using java Calendar in loop